# Wrong HDD model and serial

Tags: hard-drive, proxmox

I'm using a cheap HDD enclosure. When I plug it in it shows Proxmox that the HDD model and Serial are GENERIC and 0123456789ABCDEF, respectively. `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/` returns as "usb-JMicron_Generic_0123456789ABCDEF". This is obviously wrong. Using `lsblk -o +MODEL,SERIAL` shows the exact same result, but using `smartctl --all /dev/sdb` shows the correct information about the HDD.

Is there a way for me to fix this, and make my system recognize the HDD with the correct information the same as the smartctl result?